Закрыть окно powershell после выполнения команды
Как после выполнения команды открытия VS Code в bat файле закрыть остающееся открытым окно powershell:
start powershell -c "&{Import-Module """<....>/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 5a47adaf -StartInPath "./"; Start "code ." -NoNewWindow;}"


Добавить блок -Command "exit" ?

start powershell -c "&{Import-Module """<....>/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 5a47adaf -StartInPath "./"; Start "code ." -NoNewWindow;}" | exit

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
